# How to configure a JDBC connection to use a different AD user than the current user?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2, active-directory

The MS SQL Server 2008 R2 database *"dbname"* hosted on server *"HOSTNAME"* is accessible by an Active Directory user from domain *"ABC"*, let's call him *"dbuser"* or *"ABC\dbuser"*.

We are running our application as AD user *"ABC\appuser"*.  *"appuser"* and *"dbuser"* are in different AD groups.

When run by the service running under *"ABC\appuser"*, the connection uses user *"ABC\appuser"* to connect to the database:

```
DriverManager.getConnection(
  "jdbc:sqlserver://HOSTNAME:1433;databaseName=dbname;integratedSecurity=true", 
  "", ""
);
```

Using the same connection string and supplying the *"ABC\dbuser"* and password *"dbpass"*, the connection ignores those values and instead again attempts to use the AD info the service is running as, *"ABC\appuser"*:

```
DriverManager.getConnection(
  "jdbc:sqlserver://HOSTNAME:1433;databaseName=dbname;integratedSecurity=true", 
  "ABC\\dbuser", "dbpass"
);
```

Removing flag `integratedSecurity=true`, the connection treats *"ABC\dbuser"* as a SQL account instead of an AD account, throwing a `SQLServerException`:

```
DriverManager.getConnection(
  "jdbc:sqlserver://HOSTNAME:1433;databaseName=dbname", 
  "ABC\\dbuser", "dbpass"
);
```

throws

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
  Login failed for user 'ABC\dbuser'.
```

So far, I'm about to assume that it's not possible and that I'm going to have the database team either provide *"ABC\appuser"* AD access to the database, or put *"ABC\appuser"* into an AD group and give that AD group access to the database.  I am not provided access to configure the database; I can only provide advice/direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection string has parameters for user and password.

> user=yyy;password=xxx

Maybe try setting the credentials via the connection string and leaving the user/password parameters as empty string for your ABC\dbuser connections. I'm not sure if this will work but it's an alternate way to send credentials.

Comment: I was under the impression they just get tacked on like that anyway and the extra method parameters are just for ease of use, but I'll try `DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:sqlserver://HOSTNAME:1433;databaseName=dbname;integratedSecurity=true;user=ABC\\dbuser;password=dbpass", "", "" );` anyway and get back to you.

Comment: This worked for me.  UNFORTUNATELY, setting it as a datasource in the xml configuration for JBoss fails for me; discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704742/how-do-i-configure-a-jboss-sqlserver-datasource-to-use-ad-integrated-security-wi