# How do I configure a SQL Server datasource in JBoss to connect using a specific Active Directory user?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jboss, active-directory

JBoss runs as Active Directory user `ABC\appuser`.  I want to connect to a MS SQL Server 8.0 database as AD user `ABC\dbuser`.  Using parameter `integratedSecurity=true`, unless I specify `user=ABC\dbuser;password=dbpass` on the connection url, the system will try to connect as the service AD user, `ABC\appuser`.

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702084/how-to-configure-a-jdbc-connection-to-use-a-different-ad-user-than-the-current-u/24702718), I have confirmed that by using the following url, I can connect to the database as `ABC\dbuser` when running the application as `ABC\appuser`:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://MYHOSTNAME:1433;DatabaseName=MyDatabaseName;integratedSecurity=true;user=ABC\dbuser;password=dbpass
```

Unfortunately, when I set the url for the datasource in the JBoss configuration xml ( `JBoss\jboss-eap-6.1.0\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml` ) as follows:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MyDatabaseName" pool-name="MyPoolName" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
  <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://MYHOSTNAME:1433;DatabaseName=MyDatabaseName;integratedSecurity=true;user=ABC\dbuser;password=dbpass</connection-url>
  <driver>sqlserver</driver>
  <pool>
    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
    <prefill>true</prefill>
  </pool>
  <security>
    <user-name></user-name>
    <password></password>
  </security>
</datasource>
```

I am unable to create the pool resource with this warning:

```
WARN  
[org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (JCA PoolFiller) 
IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: 
javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
```

Setting values for `user-name` and `password` XML entries creates a similar failure warning.

My current workaround options seem to be any of:

1. extending whichever class JBoss is using to create this datasource, replacing it with a custom class that applies the `connection-url` value as expected or
2. changing JBoss to run as `ABC\dbuser` or
3. giving the JBoss service user `ABC\appuser` database access by either giving it direct access or adding it to an AD Group with access.

None of these workarounds is preferable; there must be a more elegant, accepted solution.  How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm surprised the connection string is working.  My understanding was that the integratedSecurity property in the Microsoft provided JDBC driver worked the same way as the Integrated Security or Trusted Connection properties in the equivalent .NET connection string.

That is to say that setting integratedSecurity to true makes the JDBC driver effectively ignore the user and password provided and attempt to login as the user that the application is running as.

I don't have a solution with the Microsoft SQL Server driver but this problem can be solved using the open source [jTDS JDBC Driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/).

For the large part you should be able to swap out the JDBC driver JAR file and tweak the connection XML to look something like this:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MyDatabaseName" pool-name="MyPoolName" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
  <connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MYHOSTNAME:1433/MyDatabaseName;domain=ABC</connection-url>
  <driver>jtds</driver>
  <pool>
    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
    <prefill>true</prefill>
  </pool>
  <security>
    <user-name>dbuser</user-name>
    <password>dbpass</password>
  </security>
</datasource>
```

Depending on the configuration of the SQL Server you are connecting to you may need to also add `useNTLMv2=true` to the connection URL.

i.e. the entire connection URL would be:

`jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MYHOSTNAME:1433/MyDatabaseName;domain=ABC;useNTLMv2=true`

EDIT: Unfortunately in the version of JBoss EAP you're targeting adding a new JDBC driver isn't as easy as dropping the jar in the right place.

Here are the rather cumbersome instructions for adding the new JDBC driver:

1. Create the folder JBOSS_HOME\modules\net\sourceforge\jtds\main
2. Copy the file jtds-1.3.1.jar into the folder.
3. Create a file named module.xml in the folder with the following contents

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="net.sourceforge.jtds">
     <resources>
       <resource-root path="jtds-1.3.1.jar"/>
     </resources>
     <dependencies>
       <module name="javax.api"/>
       <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
     </dependencies>
   </module>
   ```
4. Add the following XML to standalone.xml (modify the drivers element to add the driver element if it already exists)

   ```
   <drivers>
     <driver name="jtds" module="net.sourceforge.jtds">
       <driver-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
     </driver>
   </drivers>
   ```

Comment: This worked, but we did end up going (my preferred) "workaround" route and adding the AD user the service runs as, "appuser" to an AD group with access to the SQL Server database.  This is fine, as the Service AD user "appuser" was the only consumer of the DB AD user, "dbuser".

Answer (score -2):

First, I'm not even sure how the connection string you're using is working at all. If you specify trusted connection and a user/pass combo an error should be returned since using both is not possible. You either want to connect using the current account context or a specific username/password combo, not both. Even so, SQL Server does not store AD passwords nor will it authenticate a user/pass combo as anything else but a SQL Server Login.

Secondly, I'm not sure you really mean SQL Server 8.0 RC@ as RC2 would mean release candidate 2 of version 8.0 which was SQL Server 2000. If so, that is not supported at all and I would suggest migrating to 2012 or 2014.

Now, I'm not entirely well versed in JBoss but you have (as I see it) two different options.

1. Somehow, inside of JBoss when a connection to this datasource is going to be attempted the context is impersonated from the ABC\AppUser account to the ABC\DBUser account. This would need to be done inside of JBoss, unfortunately I do not believe that to be possible (though I'm not positive).
2. Give connect and impersonation permissions (only for the ABC\DBUser login) to the ABC\AppUser account inside of SQL Server. Use the JBoss datasource configuration item new-connect-sql to run the impersonation command to become ABC\DBUser inside of SQL Server (EXECUTE AS LOGIN ='ABC\DBUser' WITH NO_REVERT).